# How to check if iOS version is lower than iOS 16 using navigator.userAgent in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check iOS version by using Javascript, I have this condition

```
  if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
      //true
  }
```

and the result is ok, but I'm trying to check if iOS version is lower than 16, how can I do it?

I'm trying to avoid navigator.appVersion because [is depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/appVersion)

Comment: You should use feature detection rather than chekcing the userAgent which can be spoofed anyway

Comment: You could try [this script](https://hoohoo.top/blog/7389546/#detect-ios-version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to get the version from navigator user agent

```
let version = /iP(hone|ad|od) OS ([1-9]*)/i.exec(window.navigator.userAgent)?.[2]||NaN
if (version < 16) {
  // do your stuff here
}
```